# Automatically remove "inbox" label from messages with other labels

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters, gmail-labels

I created some filters to label my e-mails in Gmail, but all of these multiple label mails have the "inbox" label too!

How can I remove the inbox label on labeled emails? (With this configuration labeled e-mail will not show in inbox.)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Edit your filter and check the "Skip the Inbox (Archive it)" option in addition to your "Apply the label" action.

[image: filter actions]

Comment: The `Archive it` made me sceptical first but this does exactly the expected. On other E-Mail plattforms this usually means the mail is completely removed from the folders and somewhere stored in an dedicated archive ...

Answer (score 5):

`[@Ale's working solution][1] works for all new emails. Following up within the question "How can I remove the inbox label on labeled emails?" there is a further explanation as anyone follow this question may have a lot of preexisting emails with 'inbox label':`

**How to remove the inbox label retrospectively**

1. Create Labels
2. Search for emails in inbox by email address or topic
3. Select them all to go under a new label
4. Right click on selected emails and 'Move to' label 
   [image: Selected Gmail Mail By Search]
   [image: Gmail Move to - Label]
5. Now the inbox label will be removed from the retrospective emails and they will be found only under the selected label folder.
6. Follow [@Ale's working solution](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/59102/216875) to create rules for new incoming emails.

Comment: this doesn't work unfortunately when the messages already assigned the target label but the inbox is still in-place (( only works with single inbox

Comment: @Suncatcher I think I know what you mean, what I did once to account for that is rename the folder. Then create a new target folder with the correct name, then move everything to that new folder, thus also the inbox items of said label. And delete the original, an extra step, but I avoid manual work.